# How to write Hungarian to text file?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing Hungarin text to text file. I have the following code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file_name))
{
    bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250").GetBytes(String.Format("{0},{1}",
                this.old_name_txt.Text, this.new_name_txt.Text, Environment.NewLine));
    sw.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250").GetString(bytes));
    Console.WriteLine(":" + Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250").GetString(bytes));
}
```

The output in the console window is correct, however, when I open the file (It's a csv file) in Excel, the encoding is incorrect.

How can I get this to write a file with the same encoding?

Comment: Sounds like excel tries to open the file as unicode or something else and misinterprets your character data. You can set the encoding in the csv-dialog (which opens when you try to open a csv file).

Comment: What is the purpose to convert string to bytes array and then back to string?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was Excel. It had me running in circles trying everything under the sun. Turns out the files are being written correctly, but Excel was not reading them correctly. WOrdpad and any other text editor I tried worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the Encoding of your stream writer
:

```
sr= new StreamWriter(file_name, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```